# Why doesn't AWS KMS encrypt/decrypt need data key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

I am reading AWS encrypt cli document from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/kms/encrypt.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/kms/decrypt.html. I found that I am able to encrypt/decrypt without creating a data key. When I read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html, it says that I need to use KMS CMK to generate a data key which is used to encrypt my data. 
So I am confused about whether I need a data key at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMK is designed to encrypt/decrypt the data keys. Therefore, there is a limit of 4 KB on the amount of plaintext that can be encrypted in a direct call to the encrypt function. You can easily test this by passing in message larger than 4 KB.

> These operations are designed to encrypt and decrypt data keys. They use an AWS KMS customer master key (CMK) in the encryption operations and they cannot accept more than 4 KB (4096 bytes) of data. Although you might use them to encrypt small amounts of data, such as a password or RSA key, they are not designed to encrypt application data.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely using a default CMK that was created by another AWS service that uses KMS encryption.

Of course all encryption and decryption operations require a key. If you did not explicitly create one for your application, then you are using the current default key.

> Ensure that KMS Customer Master Keys (CMKs) are used by your AWS services and resources instead of default KMS keys, in order to have full control over data encryption/decryption process and meet compliance requirements. A KMS default master key is used by an AWS service such as RDS, EBS, Lambda, Elastic Transcoder, Redshift, SES, SQS, CloudWatch, EFS, S3 or Workspaces when no other key is defined to encrypt a resource for that service. The default key cannot be modified to ensure its availability, durability and security. On the other side, a KMS Customer Master Key (CMK) provides the ability to create, rotate, disable, enable and audit the encryption key used to protect the data.

See https://www.cloudconformity.com/knowledge-base/aws/KMS/default-key-usage.html